# How to swap two array elements inside a JSON file

Tags: awk, sed, perl, json, jq

I have a file like this

```
{"100":["0.00001","10","0.01"],
"101":["0.0001","100","0.1"],
"102":["1","1000","1"],
....
"103":["0.01","10000","10"]}
```

I want to swap the second number with the third, inside each array,
converting it into

```
{"100":["0.00001","0.01","10"],
"101":["0.0001","0.1","100"],
"102":["1","1","1000"],
....
"103":["0.01","10","10000"]}
```

How do I do that with `sed`, `awk`, or whatever?

Notice the existence of `{` and `}` at the first and last records.

thanks

Comment: So, why not a JSON lib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would advise to avoid parsing JSON data using text oriented tool like `awk` or `sed`, etc...

Instead use a JSON parser or a language that relies on a JSON library like `perl`, `python`, etc..

Here is an example with `jq`:

```
<file jq '.[] |= (.[2] as $t | .[2] = .[1] | .[1] = $t)'
```

All objects are replaced with the permutation of the 3rd and 2nd array element. Note that the arrays in `jq` start with index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

More verbose than jq would be to use a scripting language that has JSON libraries available:

```
ruby -rjson -e '
    data = JSON.parse File.read ARGV.shift
    data.transform_values! {|v| v[1], v[2] = v[2], v[1]; v}
    puts JSON.pretty_generate data
' file.json
```

```
perl -E '
    use Path::Tiny;
    use JSON;
    $json = JSON->new->utf8;
    $data = $json->decode( path(shift)->slurp_utf8 );
    while (($key, $val) = each %$data) {
        ($val->[1], $val->[2]) = ($val->[2], $val->[1]);
        $data->{$key} = $val;
    } 
    $json->canonical->indent;
    say $json->encode($data);
' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` and its `reverse` function:

```bash
jq '.[][1:] |= reverse' file.json
```

or

```bash
jq '.[][-2:] |= reverse' file.json
```

The expression `.[][1:]` selects slices containing all but the first element of each array in the document (`.[][-2:]` explicitly selects the last two elements in each array).  These are reversed using `reverse`.

A possibly simpler approach:

Explicitly rewriting the arrays in the order that we want them by picking the elements in the correct order:

```bash
jq 'map_values([ .[0], .[2], .[1] ])' file.json
```

This recreates each array, using the elements from the original array in the order they are picked out.